# Render CKEditor Data in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, mathml

I need to render my CKEditor Data on my web page but it's not happening as I am using vuejs, which does not refresh the page it just replaces the components.
My CKEditor data also contain MathML Formulas.
Need to load it dynamically from the rest API.
Example of data that is stored as the output of CKEditor

```
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mrow><mo>(</mo><mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msup><mi>a</mi><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>b</mi><mo>+</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></math></p>
```

rendering MathML can be done using the CDN
https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
but this thing works on page refresh and because VueJS is SPA it does not work there.
I want to render the formula in my , not in the CKEditor.
I have got the formula mentioned as an output of CKEditor but now want to display it on a normal webpage of vuejs

Comment: can you please elaborate?!